# Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask static assets 404

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I want to use Nginx to make {host1}/v2 proxy pass to another IP.

My Nginx and Gunicorn are in different two servers

Here is my configuration:

```
location /v2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7777/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

My Gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:7777 -w 1 autoapp:app
```

It worked, but Flask static response 404 not found.

static url is `http://{host}/static`

How can I config? thanks:-)

Comment: did you try `http://{host}/v2/static`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes, it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

`{host}/v2/static` can work.

I used `Flask-Webpack` extension.

so just config this argument

```
WEBPACK_ASSETS_URL = '/v2/static/'
```